# How to display a huge list of Categories and subcategories?

Tags: android, if-statement, autocomplete, switch-statement

I am building an `android` app and
I have a huge list of categories(~50) to display to the user, I am currently using an `AutoCompleteTextView` for it to allow the user to select.

but my problem is that I also have a huge list(~10 per category) of subcategories that I must display and let user pick one, Subcategories must be displayed based on the selected category/ies .

So apart from writing a huge `switch-case` or `if-else` block , How do I do this ?

I am not really sure but can reflection be used to inspect the fields of `R.java` and then get the id of resource containing the subcategories ? Assuming I use a proper naming convention of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my improvement based on inspiration from @Jordi's answer .

Using the power of regular expressions I did some modification in the huge `XML` file.

The Idea is to create a `java.util.Map<String,String[]>` , The keys are the categories and the values are the subcategories.

So I can get the list of categories by `map.keySet()` and then based on the user selection 
I can do `map.get(selection)` to get the list of sub-categories.

Comment: can you throw a sample based on that? please.

Comment: @prashant : Sorry, Its been more than 17 months since I wrote that code, I barely even remember the context in which I wrote the question. So no I don't think I can give you a sample on that :-(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should implement this using all categories and subcategories in your layouts file. I would generate the layout by the Java code so I can easily add some smart tricks.

For example, you can add "tag" values programmatically that can help you identify the selected item.